# All methods act as a HTTP verb (Get, Put, Post And Delete) in ASP.NET WEB API controller

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am building up a **ASP.NET Core 2.0 WEB API**. My controller has several methods. But, all the methods are not working when I am calling from Postman. All the time it behaves like HTTP (Get, Put, Post And Delete) verbs. So, how can I call my desired methods from client side. Or, is it okay to serve this way?

Here is my code:

```
namespace DutchTreat.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class OrdersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IDutchRepository _ctx;
        private readonly ILogger<OrdersController> _logger;

        public OrdersController(IDutchRepository _ctx, ILogger<OrdersController> logger)
        {
            this._ctx = _ctx;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(_ctx.GeAllOrders());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest("Something Went Wrong");
            }
        }

        [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
        public IActionResult GetOrdersById(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var orders = _ctx.GetOrdersById(id);

                if (orders != null)
                    return Ok(orders);
                else
                    return NotFound();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest("Something Went Wrong");
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post(Order model)
        {
            try
            {
               _ctx.AddEntity(model);
                _ctx.SaveChanges();

                return Created($"/api/orders/{model.Id}", model);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest("Something Went Wrong");
            }
        }

        public IActionResult SampleMethod()
        {
            // Sample Method Definition

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And I am requesting from Postman: http://localhost:8888/api/orders/SampleMethod
It shows **404 not found**!

Comment: What happens when you call them with postman? What response do you get?

Comment: Can you also share your controller class definition?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *All the time it behaves like HTTP (Get, Put, Post And Delete) verbs.* because I do not understand your question. Also post code and not screenshots because if someone wants to test your code, they cannot copy paste a screenshot into visual studio or another tool.

Comment: Also web api uses conventions so in your controller every action which starts with `Get` is considered an `HTTP GET` even if you do not have the `HttpGet` attribute on the method.

Comment: I am requesting this url: localhost:8888/api/orders/SampleMethod from Postman. But din't reach that method. Here, orders is my Controller name and SampleMethod is my Method name.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Thanks. Unfortunately I have lost my codes. Just let me know please, in an Api Controller all the methods works just like HTTP verbs? Can't I write any Methods and call the from Client side, using Controller name and method name?

Comment: What do you mean client side?

Comment: @ModusTollens I understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SampleMethod` is missing routing attributes, which is why it shows *404 Not Found* when called.

Update action to use an appropriately defined route template and *HTTP{Verb}*

The following example defines an HTTP GET for the action.

```
//GET api/orders/SampleMethod 
[HttpGet("SampleMethod")]
public IActionResult SampleMethod() {
    // Sample Method Definition

    return Ok();
}
```